# Gradle issue using file and filter

Tags: gradle

I am trying to loop over a map, for each key read some property files, use filter to replace some tokens. My issue is, looping happens. At the end, instead of having 5 folders, I've just 1 folder inside config. Do I need to close any resources like file/inputstream before going on to the next?

```
task copyResByHost(type: Copy) {

  java.util.HashMap hostMap = new HashMap();

  hostMap.put("devserver01","env_dev.properties");
  hostMap.put("devserver02","env_dev.properties");
  hostMap.put("devserver03","env_dev.properties");
  hostMap.put("devserver04","env_dev.properties");
  hostMap.put("devserver05","env_dev.properties");

  hostMap.each { key, value ->
    from "$projectDir/resources/templates"
    into("build/config/${key}")
    def myProps = new Properties()
    file("$projectDir/resources/properties/${value}").withInputStream {
      myProps.load(it);
    }
    file("$projectDir/resources/properties/${key}.properties").withInputStream {
      myProps.load(it);
    }
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: myProps)
  }
}
```

Can you let me know where am I making a mistake which is causing 1 folder only created instead of 5 inside config?
Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

from and into were being overwritten everytime causing only 1 folder to be created.

So code should be changed as follows:

```
hostMap.each { key, value ->
    println "Creating configs for $key"
    //inputs.dir '$projectDir/resources/templates'
    // outputs.dir 'build/config/${key}'

        doLast {
            copy {
                from("$projectDir/resources/templates")
                into("build/config/${key}")
                def myProps = new Properties()
                new File("$projectDir/resources/properties/${value}").withInputStream { stream ->
                    myProps.load(stream);
                }
                new File("$projectDir/resources/properties/${key}.properties").withInputStream { stream ->
                    myProps.load(stream);
                }
                filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: myProps)
            }
        }
    }
```

from & into, file stream everything should appear within closure doLast { copy { }  }